# Is there a way to pass a package private class to static method

Tags: java, package, static-methods, package-private

I'm wondering if there is a way to call static method from another package which take a package private class as a parameter? is that the only way to move MessagePackagePrivate class to another .java file and make it public ? it gives this error if i don't do that : "The type MessagePackagePrivate is not visible" which is normal.

So if it is the case that means, even if your class expose a static method to be used publicly ,that class cannot be used if it is not being called in the same package?

here is the code snippet:

MainClass.java

```
package packageA;

import packageB.*;

public class MainClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ClassB.printString(new MessagePackagePrivate("Package problem"), 12);
    }
}
```

ClassB.java

```
package packageB;

public class ClassB {

    public static void printString( MessagePackagePrivate message , int numbers) {
        System.out.println(message.getMessage() + " numbers: " + numbers );
        // other logics will be implemented here ...
    }
}

    class MessagePackagePrivate {
        private String text;

        MessagePackagePrivate(String text) {
            this.text = text;
        }

        public String getMessage() {
            return this.text;
        }
    }
```

Comment: It should be noted that `pacenter code herekageA` isn't a valid package name.  It'd be `pacenter.code.herekageA` instead.

Comment: your MessagePackagePrivate is a default class. Default classes cannot be referenced from other packages than itself

Comment: @Sikorski:  It's not a default class.  It's a nested class.  It's in the package `packageB`.  It has a different visibility to it than other classes in this package.

Comment: @Makoto i am with Sikorski, its not inner class, its default, two classes within one java file.

Comment: @Makoto for first time I also thought thats an inner class but then look carefully  at the file, the braces and also in question Op says that when he moves  the class in another java file it works, i dont think you would that with a nested class just to make something work

Comment: @Makoto I edited code again, package  was typo, so i updated the package name.

Comment: @Sikorski yes i'm saying when i move the class into another java file it works but as long as i make it PUBLIC (public class MessagePackagePrivate). So my question is still valid. is there any other way? Because ClassB expose a static method to be used by others, but it takes a parameter that can not be pass from another package.

Answer (score 2):

This is what interfaces are for.

You have a public interface (well, all interfaces are public) that defines all the methods that need to be publicly accessible and a package private implementation. And the method you pass the object to only needs to know about the interface.

In your case you'll have something like this:

```
public interface Message {
  public String getMessage();
}
```

And then

```
class MessagePackagePrivate implements Message {
   ...
}
```

Finally:

```
public static void printString( Message message , int numbers) {
   ...
}
```

Comment: with interface also, Op will have to somehow instantiate the object which will give same problem, or he should use some Factory pattern sorts !

Comment: @Sikorski Yes, good point. A simple `createMessage( String text )` method in `ClassB` will do in this case.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement an interface (say `Printable`) and use that interface as parameter type in your static method.